# wordpress и вывод записей

Tags: wordpress

использую последний WP, вот только вспомнить немогу:
1. Главная страница статичная, как сделать вывод всех записей после контента? через post_query помоему.
2. Как сделать два типа записей? типо "Новости" и "Проекты" был какой то плагин, но не могу вспомнить никак.

Answer (score 0):

Если я Вас правильно понял, то рубрики создаются в админ панели в разделе Рубрики.
По поводу вывода всех статей, на Вордпрессе в доках есть очень интересная статья, рекомендую ознакомится: https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB_WordPress

Answer (score 0):

1. Все правильно, но для вывода записей лучше использовать wp_query() - параметры такие же, но возможностей больше.
2. Для новостей используете стандартный тип постов "Записи", а для проектов можно создать отдельный тип записей. Вот [статья по теме](https://misha.blog/wordpress/register_post_type.html).
   Ну, или через рубрики делайте, в зависимости от задачи.